# how to convert ajax code to get JSON data into Jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<html>  
<head>   
<title>AJAX JSON </title>  
<script type="application/javascript">  
function load()  
{  
   var url = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/data.json";//use url that have json data  
   var request;  
 //XMLHttpRequest Object is Created
   if(window.XMLHttpRequest){    
    request=new XMLHttpRequest();//for Chrome, mozilla etc  
   }    
   else if(window.ActiveXObject){    
    request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");//for IE only  
   }    
 //XMLHttpRequest Object is Configured
   request.onreadystatechange  = function(){  
      if (request.readyState == 4)  
      {  
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);//JSON.parse() returns JSON object  
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML =  jsonObj.name;  
        document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = jsonObj.country;  
      }  
   }  
   request.open("GET", url, true);  
   request.send();  
}  
</script>  
</head>  
<body>  

Name: <span id="name"></span><br/>  
Country: <span id="country"></span><br/>  
<button type="button" onclick="load()">Load Information</button>  
</body>  
</html>
```

i have written the code for how to get json data using ajax code.Now i want to convert this code to get json data using jquery. Also i want to use same json url which i used in ajax code. How to get json data using jquery?

Comment: Er, `$.ajax` maybe?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Name: <span id="name"></span><br/>  
Country: <span id="country"></span><br/>  
<button type="button" id="load">Load Information</button> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#load').click(function() {
      $.get('https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/data.json', function(response) {
        $('#name').text(response.name);
        $('#country').text(response.country);
      });
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: what is meaning of "r" in get method?

Comment: It's the response JSON from the server. I updated my answer